# Why didn't Sam have the same powers as Flynn when he was in the Grid?

Tags: tron-legacy

In the first Tron movie we see that Flynn has a lot of powers (the ability to manipulate the environment) because he is a user. We see that he has similar abilities again in the second movie.

Why doesn't Sam exhibit and special abilities in the Grid for being a user?

Comment: Sam forgot to right-click and run TRON.exe in Administrator mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kevin Flynn didn't know all of this from start, he has to learn it. He also programmed a lot of things on the original grid :

> I shouldn't have written all of those tank programs.
>   - Kevin Flynn

The first time he showed his powers, He reassembled and reactivated a destroyed Recognizer, which came from [a game he wrote](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Space_Paranoids).

In Tron Legacy, Kevin Flynn is not a normal user, he is the creator of the second grid. He know everything about it, plus he [is there for a long time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/how-does-time-and-aging-work-in-the-grid-of-tron). Also note than since it's Clu that sent the call on Alan Bradley's pager, he was expecting the arrival of a user and probably set up some defence against him. Kevin, as the creator off the grid, has the knowledge AND experience to evade those, but not Sam.

Sam may have the same powers, he is a good programmer and a competent hacker, but didn't learn to use them (yet).

Comment: The destroyed Recognizer *definitely* came from a game he wrote; the Recognizers are from Space Paranoids.

Comment: Also, the Encom mainframe grew up as-is, but the Grid has been extensively altered by Clu, who has an... unfriendly user interface.  And had planned for Sam's arrival.  Flynn knows how to beat that, but he's had a *long* subjective lifespan to practice with.

Comment: @Tynam You are right, I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Tynam Clu didn't plan Sam's arrival, he was expecting Allan Bradley, but it's Sam that showed up.

Comment: Oops, good point.  (Although it doesn't actually change this answer - Clu was expecting a *user*, and prepared appropriately.)

Comment: @Tynam Insightful, I edited it again.