# If Flynn had the master key, why couldn't he just delete Clu?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

Also, since Flynn was the only one able to create new programs, why couldn't he make a second copy of himself (CLU 3.0), with a sole objective to remove CLU and maintain the current structure of the grid?

Answer (score 3):

Flynn had the master key that controlled the *[Portal](https://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Portal)*, the only exit from the Grid. The key did not allow him to create programs, but the fact that he is a *[User](https://tron.wikia.com/wiki/User)* allow him. And he is not an ordinary user, he is *The Creator* of the second Grid. (see : [Why didn't Sam have the same powers as Flynn when he was in the Grid?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8672/why-didnt-sam-have-the-same-powers-as-flynn-when-he-was-in-the-grid))

Deleting Clu from inside the grid is not as simple as it would be from the outside. To get rid of him, Flynn had to reintegrate him, whatever that means, sacrificing himself in the process. Why it had to be done that way is a mystery, but it was supposedly the only way.

As for the creation of an other copy of Clu, I suspect the problem is that Flynn doesn't have access to the resources he needs to create anything new, since Clu took control of everything in the Grid and made sure Flynn could not access it.

Comment: That makes sense, I just figured that Clu wouldn't have the ability to deny permission to his parent.

Comment: And yet Flynn built that house out in the bad lands, presumably after fleeing Clu's kudeta.

Comment: @JackBNimble Building a house and a program is different. For a house, he needed rocks, (or the digital version of rocks). To create program, he probably needed more than rocks.

Comment: @JackBNimble I would imagine the house to have been his from before CLU's overthrow.  How else would he have had the books from the real world as well as the 2nd generation Lighty Cycle he had been working on all those years ago?

Comment: @Monty129 If that is true why didn't Clu know where his house was?

Comment: @JackBNimble that I don't have a solid answer for, but speculating, I'd say because Flynn never told him where it was, or he had several "bolt holes" scattered throughout the Grid.  It could also have been a structure that was already there and Flynn merely repurposed it for himself and transplanted his personnel effects there.

Comment: Who's to say those real-world relics weren't _programs_ he wrote meticulously while in exile? But anyway, what I am wondering is, [why didn't he simply (attempt to) derez CLU the old-fashioned disc-throwing way?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102068/769)