# Did the progams know that Flynn was still in the grid?

Tags: tron-legacy

After Clu's coup d'état did programs know that Flynn didn't exit the Grid? Clu knew, because he was looking for Flynn and eventually used tactics to try and draw him out. But did the population at large know that Flynn was lost somewhere in the Grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grid's population thought that Flynn was either dead or that he had abandoned them to flee the grid.

Remember that Flynn hid himself, and he did it very well for a [very long time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/how-does-time-and-aging-work-in-the-grid-of-tron). In the programs' view, he became some kind of mystical god that everybody had heard about but nobody had actually seen since he vanished. Castor also mentions that the faith in the user was going downhill since Flynn's disappearance. It becomes, as [some](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Conan_Antonio_Motti) would say, a *sad devotion to an ancient religion*.

> I believed in users once before.

Also, just before the light-cycle battle, Jarvis goes into a speech where he mentions that the presence of a users was barely a rumor :

> Greetings programs.
>   Oh what a location we have here before us.
>   Because, your rumors are true.
>   We do indeed have in our midst, a user.
>   Aaa uuuser.

Comment: What disturbs me is that the program easily recognize Flynn. Making it mandatory for them to have seen him recently in one way or another. What you think ?

Comment: @Xaltar Not necessarily mandatory: CLU is Fynn's Doppelgänger, so it's easy for them to remember how he look like.

Comment: @Xaltar - Why would a program forget anything?

Comment: @DavRob60 : I think that strange, because now he doesn't look like the same anymore.

Comment: @Jack : I never said they do. What makes you think I did ?

Comment: @Xaltar, why else would you be surprised they recognize Flynn. "Making it mandatory for them to have seen him recently in one way or another" What is time to a program?

Comment: @Jack : But if he grows old, his face changes. And they recognize him immediately ... how is that so ?