# What exactly does the application that Kevin Flynn is trapped in do?

Tags: tron-legacy

So watching Tron Legacy and we are told Kevin Flynn designed the games "Tron" and "Space Paranoids".

A very simple question,
So what exactly is the purpose of the application that he has been trapped in for 21 years do? What is it designed to do? Was there a purpose for it?

Comment: The Grid isn't an application,  it's the graphical representation of an existing operating system. The Grid 2.0 isn't even that, it's just a workspace.

Comment: @Valorum, but they are transported into an application, what is it?

Comment: Can you offer a timestamp? Or do you just mean [The Grid](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Grid) in general?

Answer (score 3):

It was essentially a digital research facility.  As per the [Tron Wiki](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/Grid):

> the Grid was made to provide an experimental platform where all forms of research could be carried out at unparalleled speeds. Perceived time on the Grid is measured in cycles and run at a pace far greater than time perceived in the real world, thus allowing anyone immersed in the computer environment to perform the same functions in a fraction of the time it would take them otherwise.

So the idea was that Flynn could digitize himself and others in to the Grid and perform experiments at a much faster pace in the real world. People in the Grid [age at the same rate as the real world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/how-does-time-and-aging-work-in-the-grid-of-tron?rq=1), but they experience time at a much, much faster pace. So in theory, research that takes years would only take hours or days.

This of course did not work out so well, but this was the intent.

Comment: Of note, the Tron wiki has zero citations. Can you back any of this up with canon source material?

Comment: @phantom42: That is true.  The only thing I can find in the dialog is was Flynn mentioning he built the Grid with Clu. They were building a "Utopia" until they end up discovering life that manifested itself in the program. Then Clu gets angry and the story goes on. You could say Flynn just wanted to build a world, but they never finished to see what his ultimate plan was. I would say researching being digitized, living in a computer, and creating life would be within the realm of scientific research though.